# Condition for infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & -4 \\
4 & 3 & -12 \\
1 & 2 & -8 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x \\
y \\
z \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha \\
5 \\
7 \end{array} \right)$$
For how many values of $\alpha$ does this system of equations have infinitely many solutions ?
This was the question I have to solve.
Now I know since 3rd column is scalar multiple of 2nd column, so column space $C(A)$ of coefficient matrix $A$ is a 2D plane in 3D space.
So there is only one value of $\alpha$, which will put this vector $b$ into that 2D plane. Now my question is do we have infintely many solutions then, I mean I can't understand how  there are multiple linear combinations of 3 column vectors of $A$ such that it results into same vector $b$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the system has a kernel; since the column space is not 3-dimensional there are nontrivial linear combinations of the columns that vanish, namely multiples of $x=0,y=4,z=1$. So given one solution, you find another by adding any element of this kernel. Do be sure to check your claim about there being exactly one $\alpha,$ though: not every line intersects every plane, and a given line intersects some planes infinitely often.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am a beginner in linear algebra, and learning it by watching Gilbert strang's lectures, and I am not up to the point of understanding kernels etc. I wanted a just visual clue about infinitely many solutions, because I have that clue in system in 2 variables.

Comment: Hm, how to restate this? A whole line gets sent to each point of your matrix's column space. So there are infinitely many vectors mapping to each point of the column space.